# Is XmlTextReader supported in Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cross-platform, portable-class-library

According to the [list of available namespaces in a PCL project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `System.Xml` is incldued. However, I get compile errors when referencing `XmlTextReader`, which is within System.Xml namespace.

I target .NET 4.0 + Silverlight 5 (Profile14). I also tried .NET4.0.3 + SL (Profile19) and .NET 4.5 + SL (Profile24), all the same.

So is `XmlTextReader` supposed to be available in a PCL, and if not, where can I find the definite list of what Classes are available and what not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not, but you can use `XmlReader.Create()` instead. BTW, it's the recommended solution [for full .Net too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Note**
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create XmlReader instances by using the XmlReader.Create method to take advantage of new functionality.

As usual, there's s [a tool for that](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b). And [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingReadyForTheFutureWithTheMicrosoftNETPortabilityAnalyzer.aspx) is a short intro to it.